# ms access 2007 SQL "not like" is ignoring blank cells

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I'm confused by some SQL I am trying to run. Here's a sample dataset

```
Username ID        Text1
red55   1235342     fdfdf
black   5542121     sdsd
red32   5542145     sffrds
green   5542911         
bluee   5333121     ffds
```

So the SQL would be

```
SELECT username, ID, Text1 
  FROM user_info
 WHERE username NOT LIKE 'red*' 
       AND text1 NOT LIKE 'sd*';
```

So I would expect to see a result set of

```
Username ID        Text1
green   5542911         
bluee   5333121     ffds
```

But it doesn't work. It seems to ignore the blank values. I would only see the one record (not like the two above). I need my SQL to simply say show me the records which dont start "red" AND also any records which don't start with "sd". Yet it either gets rid of them all AND blanks, or if I use an OR statement, gets rid of none.

Any ideas? I am stuck here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly handle the nulls.  One option would be:

```
SELECT username, ID, Text1 
FROM user_info 
WHERE (username Is Null OR username NOT LIKE 'red*')
  AND (text1 Is Null OR text1 NOT LIKE 'sd*')
```

Comment: Another option is to 'design-out' nullable columns.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I like the suggestion, but there are several ways of doing that. Any comments on that, or pointers to discussions of it elsewhere. My thinking on options are: 1. changing data types, 2. defining default values or 3. converting columns to rows in another table. An intriguing topic, as is almost anything concerning schema design for me.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "How To Handle Missing 
Information Without Using NULL" by Hugh Darwen (http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf), though IIRC you've already read and hated it ;)

Comment: Ah, yes -- *that* article. I do hate it. It's got a lot of complete insanity in it. There's nothing wrong with Nulls, but there can be good reasons for designing them out of a system on a case-by-case basis. But I would certainly never make a principle of doing so.